# Is there a way to put the chart or chart with dashboards in AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, charts, dashboard, lightningchart

I'm wondering if there's a way use LightningChart JS in Angular project? Is there some tutorial or example project for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found a Github [AngularJS template project](https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-ng-template) for Lightningchart